# How to display some more information when moving the mouse pointer over a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I am using rails v3.2.2 and jquery-rails v2.0.2 ruby-gems. I would like to display some more information when I move the mouse pointer over a button like, for example, Facebook, Google and other companies makes in their applications.

The following is a screenshot from Google Gmail that shows what I would like to implement in my application:

[image]

**How and what can I do?**

Comment: What mark-up are you working from?

Comment: this link could help to find what you want : http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Comment: Yes. ...but what structure does your HTML mark-up take? Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) jQuery tooltip plugin.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to accomplish that, using CSS and/or JavaScript. Here is a basic CSS solution:

**HTML**

```html
<button>Button text</button>
<div class="tooltip">Tooltip Content</div>​
```

**CSS**

```css
.tooltip { display: none; }
button:hover+.tooltip { display: block; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b7AF7/

Answer (score 1):

What about using `title` attribute on your button tag?

Something like:

```
<input type="button" title="your message" value="Button" />
```

Comment: I would like to give to the informational text some styling. It is possible to make that for `title` attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a tooltips library, of which there are many, including:

- Poshy: http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/
- ColorTip: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/07/colortips-jquery-tooltip-plugin/colortips.html
- Grumble: http://jamescryer.github.com/grumble.js/

A web search will turn up many more.